# Transition animation from one webpage to another

Tags: javascript, css, html

On the webpage that I am currently developing the user has an option to get redirected to another webpage via the click of a button.

At the moment the redirection works as per normal; the user clicks the button and is immediately redirected to the new webpage.

What I would like done is for the new webpage to load up first before being displayed and have a sliding in transition. At the moment I found [this site](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/) that shows me how to do this if I were to change the source html on both webpages.

But is there any way to do this if I wanted to transition from my webpage to some other arbitrary webpage like transition into Google for example?

Comment: From a user experience point of view I would advice against this, because it can be confusing to a user to not load/move to a new page in the way their browser normally would. You might fade out your site with a message, then forward them the traditional way.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to load an arbitrary page in an iframe and fade it in, covering your current page.

Edit: Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7N45/) for a Demo. But note, that this only works with pages that allow loading in frames. It won't work with google.com.